# Openshift : Spring boot : log4j settings -- configuration and finding the application log file

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, openshift, log4j2

My Spring boot application on Redhat/Openshift uses the shown log4j2.xml file.

**The issue is that I cannot find the application log file.**

My questions are:

- Below I describe the way of configuring the log4j logging for Spring boot on Openshift. Is this correct?
- Where can I find the application logging file logs/app2.log? It is not on Openshift.
- Yes, I know that there is also an app.log file via the application-openshift.properties setting. That one is never changed. Why?

I was adviced to use this in de application-openshift.properties file. Leaving these lines out has no consequences.

```
logging.file = ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/logs/app.log
logging.level = INFO
```

My src/main/resources/log4j2.xml file contains the following. I configured it also for Console for local testing. Yes, later I could distinguish per environment (not for now).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="logs/app2.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="nl.xyz.mod" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="nl.xyz.mod" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it!

The change in the log4j2.xml file is marked with ** ... ***.

You can specify a good target for the log file via an OpenShift environment variable. Within the log4j2.xml file you can specify this via ${env:OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <!-- ** location of the file is: ${env:OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/logs/app2.log" ** --> 
        <File name="File" fileName="${env:OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/logs/app2.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="nl.deholtmans.tjm1706" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="nl.deholtmans.tjm1706b" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```